# Is there a luminosity class for brown dwarfs?

Tags: brown-dwarf, spectral-type, stellar-classification

I've been reading about brown dwarfs, and checking their spectral types, and I noticed that they do not have a luminosity class (V, VI, etc). So I am wondering, do brown dwarfs have a luminosity class, or is it intentionally absent, or is it defaultly V or VI?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [SIMBAD page for the binary brown dwarf Epsilon Indi B](http://simbad.u-strasbg.fr/simbad/sim-id?Ident=eps%20ind%20B&NbIdent=1&Radius=2&Radius.unit=arcmin&submit=submit%20id) lists the components as T1V and T6V, indicating they use the normal dwarf luminosity class V.

There are also T subdwarfs, e.g. [Burningham et al. (2014)](https://academic.oup.com/mnras/article/440/1/359/2891861) give the spectral type of ULAS J131610.28+075553.0 as sdT6.5. This follows the usual convention I've seen where subdwarfs are written with a prefixed "sd" rather than using the Roman numeral luminosity class VI.

Schneider et al. (2020) also indicate that WISEA J041451.67-585456.7 and WISEA J181006.18-101000.5 are extreme subdwarfs, of spectral classes esdT0±1. Again this is indicated by a prefix ("esd") rather than a Roman numeral luminosity class. They also mention 2MASS 05325346+8246465 as being of spectral type esdL7.

[Zhang et al. (2018)](https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2018MNRAS.480.5447Z/abstract) list a number of L subdwarfs (sdL), extreme subdwarfs (esdL) and ultra-subdwarfs (usdL).